# Format error message avoiding newlines in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am exploring the possibilities of `cat()` and `message()` to format the output of my functions.

When I use `cat(fill = TRUE)` a new line is added to the end of the message, which allows for nice printing of subsequent messages. When I set `fill = FALSE`, these messages are printed in the same line.

For some reason, this printing behavior changes, when I run the code non-interactively and knit the code to via rmarkdown. *The message once in a single line is now separated across multiple lines - and I cant figure out why or how to fix this.* (this is not the case for interactive sessions, say in Rstudio)

Please see the minimal example below and try it interactivly to see the difference.

### Rmarkdown Output

```r
print_messages <- function(newline = TRUE){
  cat("1st line", fill = newline)
  message("2nd line")
}

print_messages()
#> 1st line
#> 2nd line
print_messages(newline = FALSE)  # this is, where the difference occurs
#> 1st line
#> 2nd line
```

### Interactive Output

```r
print_messages <- function(newline = TRUE){
  cat("1st line", fill = newline)
  message("2nd line")
}

print_messages()
#> 1st line
#> 2nd line
print_messages(newline = FALSE)  # this is, where the difference occurs
#> 1st line2nd line
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact, that normal chunk output and messages are handled seperately in corresponding [hooks](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks). In the process linebreaks (`\n`) are inserted before and after the output of `cat()` as well as `message()`. You can shed light on this by doing the following at the beginning of your RMarkdown document:

````
```{r, echo = F}
defMessageHook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("message")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options) {
    x <- defMessageHook(x, options)  # Apply default hook
    print(x)
    return(x)
})
```
````

Here we save the default message hook and redefine it. In the new hook we apply the default hook and add a `print()` statement to see what the default hook made out of our message (check the R Markdown panel next to your console):

````
[1] "\n\n```\n## 2nd line\n```\n\n"
[1] "\n\n```\n## 2nd line\n```\n\n"
````

As you can see, the Markdown code chunk is wrapped by linebreaks.

Comment: This seems right on the money! :) Do you have a suggestion how to best turn this off for a couple of code chunks? Probably overwrite the hook temporarily? (I didn't find out yet, where exactly the extra linebreaks are introduced in the `message` and `output` hooks or how to best modify them.)

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? The default behavior makes sense in my eyes.

Comment: Yes, it does. But I want to demonstrate the importance of adding "\n" to your messages and the knitr output doesn't allow me to present a good example.

(hardcopied the output into the chunk and set `eval=FALSE` for now)

Comment: If that is all, then why not choose `cat("1st line") cat("2nd line")` instead of mixing both types of output?